# Find utilized space of Ceph RBD in Openstack

Tags: openstack, ceph

I've got an Openstack setup using Ceph for storage. Now I've one challenge that how can I ascertain the actual utilized space for a volume.

The issue is that the sysadmin needs to login to every VM to ensure that the volume isn't full but that's not possible for production.

Comment: Did you found answer to this, I'm looking for the same

Answer (score 0):

`sudo vgdisplay cinder-volumes` .. cinder-volumes is name of my cinder volume.